# From array of indicies, create an array of the values at those indicies

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-indexing

This is for a Machine Learning problem (in Python of course).

I have a 2 dimensional array, the rows are set of points, and the columns are indices into another 1 dimensional array of values for those points.

```
data = [[1,3,2], [3,3,1], [5,1,2]]
# yes there are duplicates in the labels
labels = [2,8,9,8,8,9]
```

What I need is to create a 2D array that is the original data array, but where the values in it are now the value from labels that the index represented.

```
new_data = [[8,8,9], [8,8,8], [9,8,9]]
```

I can do this with for loops obviously. I'm asking here in case numpy or something has a call that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the indices as [indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
np.array(labels)[np.array(data)]
```

The output of an [advanced](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) ([integer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)) index is the shape of the index array (`data`).

Comment: That works perfectly. But I can't find where that is explained in the links you provided. I'm sure I'm missing it, but can you list the text on that page to search for to find where it explains this syntax. This is powerful and I want to fully understand it.

Comment: @DavidThielen. The last link on integer indexing completely explains what's going on. It's a bit more general than what you have here, which may make it harder to understand initially. Since the label array is 1D in your case, you only have one index. Each element of `data` extracts an element of `labels` and places it into the same position in the output as the index was in `data`.

Comment: Thank you - and this is a really cool feature.